# How to calculate $n$th term in terms of constants?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fractions

The expression is 
$$\large t_n=\frac{(x\times t_{n-1})^2}{((x-t_{n-1}\times y)^2+4\times x\times t_{n-1})\times t_{n-2}}$$
where $x$ and $y$ are constants.

$t_0$ , $t_1$ , $t_2$ , $t_3$ and $t_4$ are known.

How to calculate $t_n$?

Comment: The one interesting thing is that you can write it as $t_n t_{n-2}=f(t_{n-1})$ which looks like a kind of interpolation formula (and is left-to-right symmetric).

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any discernable pattern.  $t_n$ is a complicated rational function of $x$, $y$, $t_3$ and $t_4$.